# How does import statement look for a module from installed node modules in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I just want to know one thing,

Consider i have defined a dependency  in `package.json` file like `"some-library": "1.0.0"` 
and installed it using `npm install`. which will include all dependencies to `node_modules` folder.

then am importing a Component from that dependency using

`import SomeLibrary from 'some-library;`

when we do this where this `import` statement start looking for the component which we are importing ?

can some one explain in a better way. i have googled alot but didn't find any relevant answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 1):

At it's core, the import statement uses the same module resolution method as require().

So for installed modules it goes like this: By calling require(X), it gets a list of all the 'node_modules' directories present in the parent directories. Then, it tries to load the X module from each of those directories (either as a single file, or a directory.)

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together